Knill error correction
I am currently reading Gottesman's textbook notes on QEC and fault-tolerant QC. The text is great. A link to the pdf text is https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2024/cmsc858G/QECCbook-2024-ch1-15.pdf
However, I have some problems understanding the details of Knill error correction on pages 216-219. I understand how the $X$ and $Z$ errors propagate between the data and first ancilla block. When we do the measurements on each physical qubit in the end, we get two bit strings. These are then supposed to be error syndromes if $P$ are generators for a stabilizer. How does this work? And how can these measurements be used to teleport and correct the data state?
Thank you very much for your help. It would be so helpful if someone could explain this to me!
